# Why is Eclipse executing an older version of my Java program?

Tags: java, eclipse

My program had a bug that resulted in a ClassCastException being thrown. I omitted the lines in my program that resulted in this exception, and made a few other small changes, but every time I run it, it appears as though the older version of the program is being run, since the ClassCastException is still thrown and the stacktrace refers to nonexistent lines in the program!

Any idea why this is? Restarting Eclipse did not help.

Comment: How exactly are you running it? For example, are you executing class files which are built from an Ant target?

Comment: @BalusC Just did Project > Clean, and now I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @Jon I'm just rightclicking it and selecting Run Configuration As > Java Application

Comment: You've a compilation error in your code and hence no class is generated and hence the `NoClassDefFoundError` (so after all, Ralph's answer hit the nail on the head). Check the *Markers* (or *Problems*) tab in Eclipse's right bottom box to find compilation errors, or just track the red crosses on project explorer. Finally just fix those compilation errors accordingly in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Eclipse can not compile a class due to a syntax error, it will use the last compilable version to run, until the current one is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

What tends to help in these cases is to clean the build. Go to project, then select clean. In the resulting dialog you can select what to clean. Clean all would also resolve dependency issues.

Comment: Hmm I tried this, but now Eclipse is throwing a NoClassDefFoundError! Any idea as to why? I even directly added the enclosing project to the buildpath, and still the error is thrown...

Comment: Is your build actually clean? NoClassDefFoundError generally means that the class isn't there.

Comment: was having the same issue but project -> clean worked for me.

Comment: What worked for me was that my project was dependent on other project which had some errors. So I removed that project dependency by 
Right click > Configure build path > Selecting the project in which my project was dependent upon > Remove.