# Java eclipse runs older version of my code

Tags: java, eclipse

A weird issue suddenly appeared. I cannot execute my current code. Eclipse executes older version of my code.

I have read some solutions about this, but none of them worked on my project.

I did `Project > Clean` and `Project > Build Automatically`
, change content of my project as `System.out.println("hello");` and Eclipse still executes older version of my code.

This is the code that needs to be executed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

        HTable hTable = new HTable(config, "users");

        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("2")); 

        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("username"),
        Bytes.toBytes("usr"),Bytes.toBytes("dino"));

        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("password"),
        Bytes.toBytes("pass"),Bytes.toBytes("123"));

        hTable.put(p);
        System.out.println("data inserted");

        hTable.close();

    }
```

And this is the older version of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

HTable table = new HTable(config, "myLittleHBaseTable");

Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));

p.add(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"),
Bytes.toBytes("Some Value"));

table.put(p);

Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));
Result r = table.get(g);
byte[] value = r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"), Bytes
.toBytes("someQualifier"));
}
```

I found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374412/why-is-eclipse-executing-an-older-version-of-my-java-program) which says if there is a syntax error, eclipse runs old code. I removed all my codes, and wrote `System.out.println("hello");` and it still keeps executing older version of my code.

[Second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823553/eclipse-opens-old-versions-of-my-project) did not help me either. I have only one workspace and I currently am using it.

Comment: Try rebuilding the solution. If you have an error it won't run the new stuff

Comment: It does not show any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using Play Framework, I just went to path of my project, and wrote "play eclipsify" and the current code works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your code on any server then there might be a jar or war file that is being used for deployment. But if it is a simple hello world program then try re importing your project then rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Play Framework (as mentioned in your own answer), you should try:

1. `activator clean`, then
2. `activator compile` to rebuild.

Replace `activator` with `play` if you're not using TypeSafe Activator.

This may be a more direct approach than re-eclipsifying your project.